# $X$ Banach space, $Y$ normed space. $A: X \to Y$ continuous and linear and $A(X)$ of 2nd category in $Y$. Show that $A(X)=Y$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $Y$ a normed space, $A: X \to Y$ continuous and linear and let $A(X)$ be of [2nd category](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondCategory.html) in $Y$.

> Show that $A(X)=Y$ and $Y$ is a Banach space

I tried the following (by contradiction): assume $A(X) \subsetneq Y$, then $A(X)$ has empty interior: $A(X)^°=\emptyset$. The following steps would be that $A(X)\subseteq Y$ is nowhere dense, therefore it is of 1st category, which is a contradiction. For $A(X)$ to be nowhere dense, I need that $A(X)$ is closed. Is $A(X)$ closed? Why?

And why is $A(X)$ complete?

Comment: The hypothesis should say $2nd$ category in $Y$. $2nd$ category in itself will not do.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks! Edited

Comment: Repeat the proof of open mapping theorem (which usually uses baire category theorem), what do you get?

Comment: @user58955 We only proved the following version: Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces and $A: X \to Y$ surjective, continuous and linear. Then $A$ is open. So my plan was to show that $A(X)=Y$ (meaning $A$ is surjective), then somehow showing that $A(X)=Y$ is complete and then applying our theorem. What would you say? I googled a bit and everyone started showing that $A$ is open. Can I somehow apply our theorem to directly say that $A$ is open?

Comment: @user772263 Not applying the theorem, but looking into the proof of that theorem, and see how you can adapt it to your case.